# Create two columns from two different sized columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create two columns from two lists.

I tried using zip to build the DataFrame and insert the lists, but the larger list was cut off.

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ['new book revealing', 'library for topic modelling']
list2 = ['potentially embarrassing', 'several international', 'daily newspaper'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list1, list2)), columns =['list1', 'list2'])
```

My output:

```
                 list1            list2
0   new book revealing            potentially embarrassing
1   library for topic modelling   several international
```

Good output:

```
                 list1            list2
0   new book revealing            potentially embarrassing
1   library for topic modelling   several international 
2                                 daily newspaper
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
import itertools
pd.DataFrame(itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2), columns =['list1', 'list2'])
```

---

```
                        list1                     list2
0           new book revealing  potentially embarrassing
1  library for topic modelling     several international
2                         None           daily newspaper
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and transpose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([list1, list2]).T.fillna('')
# df.columns = ['list1', 'list2']

                    0                         1
0           new book revealing  potentially embarrassing
1  library for topic modelling     several international
2                                      daily newspaper
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a horizontal df and then transpose.

```
pd.DataFrame([list1, list2], index=['list1', 'list2']).T.fillna('')

    list1                       list2
0   new book revealing          potentially embarrassing
1   library for topic modelling several international
2                               daily newspaper
```